# How to get specific image in media library with php

Tags: php, functions, images

I am new to Wordpress. I am trying to get an image src from one of my images in my media library without having to mention my domain or having to do some external link.

Say I have an image with an id of 20,

instead of writing something static like,

"`<img src ="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/example.png">`"

I could do something like "`<img src="<?php echo get_image_by_id(20); ?>">`".

I know get_image_by_id function doesn't exist but is there anything similar to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few functions:

- [`wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, $size )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) - Gets the URL to specified size of the image.
- [`wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) - Gets an array of the image URL, width, and height for the specified size of the image.
- [`wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) - Gets the full HTML for an image, including width, height, alt, sizes and srcset attributes. If you intend on outputting an HTML `<img>` tag, use this.